# How to add number of days to existing ng-module date in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I'm new to angularjs actually i'm trying to add one `ng-module` value into another ng-moudule `date input` in angularjs...
For exmaple:- 17-08-2016  add 20  Result Expecting 03-09-2016.
[my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1t1trzxzk3Dd9jbgqcPi)

i don't know where i did the mistake and how to get the solution, please if anyone knows the answer help me for the same thanks.

**My controller**

```
 $scope.name = {
"_id": "57ac1b6d82e1c5940ac3c730",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"terms": "20",
"invoice_date": "2016-08-17",
"due_date": ""
};

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(terms));
    return this;
};
```

**My Html:-**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="mani in name"> </tr>
      <td >{{name.invoice_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
          <td >{{name.terms }}</td>
             <td >{{name.invoice_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}} + {{name.terms }}</td>
```

Comment: I can't see where are you using `addDays`. I can see the you defined it but never used. Do you mean that you want to add days in the last column?

Comment: Hi mosh feu thanks for your comment , can u please provide the solution for how to use `addDays` in `HTML` and the better way to provide the solution via in plunker.....please suggest whether we have used the controller function is perfect or not...please help me for the same....

Comment: @ Mosh Feu :- i have mentioned the expecting result in above , Please provide the solution in plunker....advance thanks for your answer...

Comment: Seems that @Armo answer a good answer. Isn't?

Comment: @Mosh Feu...thanks for your valuable comment i got the answer with help of Mr.Arno.....

Comment: I'm glad to hear :) Good luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by doing this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
"_id": "57ac1b6d82e1c5940ac3c730",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"terms": "20",
"invoice_date": "2016-08-17",
"due_date": ""
};

$scope.addDays = function(stringDate,days) {
   var date = new Date(stringDate);
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  return date;
}

});
```

then in your template do:

```
 <td >{{addDays(name.invoice_date,name.terms) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
```

the reason why something like this doesn't work in your example:

```
<td >{{(name.invoice_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy').addDays({{name.terms}})}} + {{name.terms }}</td>
```

is because the angular date filter returns a String representation and thus is not linked to the date prototype

in theory this could work if your name.invoice_date would be a date object instead of a string in your json.
take a look at this from the angular filter source code

```
@param {(Date|number|string)} date Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or
 *    number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its
 *    shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
 *    specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.
```

so if it would be a date to begin with you could do:

```
<td >{{(name.invoice_date).addDays({{name.terms}}) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}} + {{name.terms }}</td>
```

Comment: Hi `Arno_Geismar` thank you soo much buddy ....it's works perfectly....

Comment: Hi Mr.Arno_Geismar...while i implementing your code  i got error like this :- `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: ngModelWatch; newVal: \"2016-08-22T00:00:00.000Z\"; oldVal: \"2016-08-22T00:00:00.000Z\""],`  so if you the solution pls help us .....thanks ...

Comment: then i used ng-bind like this:- ng-bind="due_date=addDays(sryarndebitnote.invoice_date,sryarndebitnote.terms) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"...i thing here is the problem found .it's showing output  like:-  Mon Aug 22 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST) so let us know the solution please...

Comment: Hi @ Arno ...do u know the solution of the given errors?

Comment: Hi the error you are getting happens when your code changes the date value while the digest loop of angular is running. Angular does 2 loops (dirty checking) of all the watchers to make sure nothing changed and it needs to update the view. When you change something during this phase it runs again until finally after 10 try's angular gives this error. I don't know how to fix this since it is vague and depends on your code. But something is continuously updating the model of the date value causing this error

Comment: Thanks for your comments, by any chance if you know the solution please help me , for your referrence i have given my plunker :- http://plnkr.co/edit/R1Qn8X1XZel5pZqvaBmM?p=preview please look my plunker help me for the same....

Comment: what are you trying to do with the text input ? If you want to modify the enddate then you are better of using a datepicker